# How to pass Model field value into a javascript variable?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

`<%: Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Name) %>`

```
<script> 
var name = <%: Model.Name %> 
alert(name);
</script>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to put quotes around the value so that it is considered as a string:

```
var name = '<%: Model.Name %>';
alert(name);
```

But if you already have the value inside a hidden field:

```
<%: Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Name) %>
```

you could read it like this:

```
var name = document.getElementById('Name').value; // make sure the id is Name
alert(name);
```

or using jquery:

```
var name = $('#Name').val();
alert(name);
```